# Auth.log full of did not receive identification string from xx.xx.xx.xx

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-web-services

My sshd server is running on an AWS EC2 instance and you have configured it behind an Elastic Load Balancer with a health check on the SSH port, I am seeing the below message in auth.log each time the health check runs.My /var/log/auth.log is full of these messages, spammed every  second. The IPs( xx.5) are from our internal LB Ips.

```
Jul  8 09:49:16 ip-10-0-xx-11 sshd[10494]: Did not receive identification string from 10.0.xx.5
Jul  8 09:49:17 ip-10-0-xx-11 sshd[10495]: Did not receive identification string from 10.0.xx.5
Jul  8 09:49:18 ip-10-0-xx-11 sshd[10496]: Did not receive identification string from 10.0.xx.5
Jul  8 09:49:19 ip-10-0-xx-11 sshd[10497]: Did not receive identification string from 10.0.xx.5
Jul  8 09:49:20 ip-10-0-xx-11 sshd[10498]: Did not receive identification string from 10.0.xx.5
Jul  8 09:49:21 ip-10-0-xx-11 sshd[10499]: Did not receive identification string from 10.0.xx.5
Jul  8 09:49:21 ip-10-0-xx-11 sshd[10500]: Did not receive identification string from 10.0.xx.5
Jul  8 09:49:22 ip-10-0-xx-11 sshd[10502]: Did not receive identification string from 10.0.xx.5
Jul  8 09:49:22 ip-10-0-xx-11 sshd[10503]: Did not receive identification string from 10.0.xx.5
Jul  8 09:49:22 ip-10-0-xx-11 sshd[10505]: Did not receive identification string from 10.0.xx.5
Jul  8 09:49:22 ip-10-0-xx-11 sshd[10505]: Did not receive identification string from 10.0.xx.5
```

So how can I prevent only these messages from getting logged to auth.log ?

Comment: I would try switching to a NLB. Makes more sense for a non-http service such as SSH.

Comment: In my case, request flows from NLB --> ALB-> EC2

Comment: Checked with aws support. Nothing on NLB side. we have to take care on Server side.